# How to get the default encoding of current OS in perl script？

Tags: perl, encoding

How can I get the default encoding used by current platform？
Is there any available module in CPAN or with the distribution of Perl itself？
I can't find the solution in perl.org

Comment: Encoding of what? File system names? Console streams?

Answer (score 1):

See I18N::Langinfo.

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 perl -MI18N::Langinfo=langinfo,CODESET -E 'say langinfo(CODESET())'
UTF-8
$ LANG=C perl -MI18N::Langinfo=langinfo,CODESET -E 'say langinfo(CODESET())'
ANSI_X3.4-1968
$ LANG=ja_JP.eucjp perl -MI18N::Langinfo=langinfo,CODESET -E 'say langinfo(CODESET())'
EUC-JP
```

This is probably what you're looking for.  If you follow the code in I18N::Langinfo, you can see how it discovers what locale to use for returning this.

Comment: This is the correct approach, see also [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210602/how-to-determine-if-current-locale-uses-utf-8-encoding) question.